# Unity 3d (URP) Glass

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, mat

I want to make a transparent glass in Unity URP i first try to get the transparent down but even when i change the alpha value to 50 - 70 and change the color it does match the color what i want when i change the value of the metalic it's color change to black the material what i want it look like is

[image: transparent object]

the material shader of what i am using is URP/Lit

i tried to get to a shader from githup but it didn't work

[image: the object with the glass shader]

second i tried to make my own shader but i got with alot of bugs and i didn't do anything
all what i want is a glass even if it's like 60% correct of the real material